# Cobertura not recognizing JUnit4 tests: No tests found

Tags: ant, junit4, findbugs, cobertura

I am currently upgrading from JUnit3 to JUnit4 and I have changed my main test suite to use the @SuiteClasses annotation. However now when I run cobetura it can't find any tests. I have checked to ensure I am seeing the right jar in the Cobertura directory, and the old tests (JUnit3) still work fine.

Also JUnits (Both tests and suites) ran by themselves work fine.

I am sure it may be an issue in the Ant xml files I am using but I can't find it anywhere.

This could also be an issue with findbugs.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the real question? How cobertura is connected to finding which tests to run?  Are you able to run tests without cobertura? Please post relevant ant file content

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Ant 1.6.5 is not compatible with JUnit4